# How to pass javascript variable value to google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to pass the value from javascript to google maps v3.
Here i have php code that is getting the lat and lon values from database and generating table for one record.

i am getting lat and lon from that table and alerting that value.Now i want to pass the lat and lon values to the google maps, onclick. how can i do this?

Code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['theater_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id='lat'>" . $row['lat'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id='lon'>" . $row['lon'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

The above code is generating the table using php code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getvalue()
{
var lat = document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML;
var lon = document.getElementById('lon').innerHTML;
alert(lat+","+lon);
}
</script>
```

The above javascript function is getting the lat and lon value from the table.

Now i want to pass the lat and lon values to the below goole maps api to lat and lon

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.955649,77.570837),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  }


  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

In place of `(12.955649,77.570837)` i want to get the lat and lon value that the javascript function is getting from table

Answer (score 2):

Just pass them in to `initialize` as parameters. You may have to use `parseInt` on the values as they will be returned as strings using `getElementById(x).innerHTML` rather than integers.

```
function getvalue() {
  var lat = parseInt(document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML, 10);
  var lon = parseInt(document.getElementById('lon').innerHTML, 10);
  initialize(lat, lon);
}

function initialize(lat, lon) {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
}
```